# Confidence intervals positioned central on a group bar

Tags: matlab, plot, bar-chart, confidence-interval

So I try to implement the solution from this post:

[How to compute confidence intervals and plot them on a bar plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57316893/how-to-compute-confidence-intervals-and-plot-them-on-a-bar-plot)

At first, I thought it was correct so I marked it as answer, but it was later when I noticed that the confidence intervals are all in the middle of each bar group.

[image]

The code:

```
for c = 1:3
    size(means(:, c))
    size(b(c).XData)
    e = errorbar(b(c).XData + b(c).XOffset, means(:,c), ci95(:, c));
    e.LineStyle = 'none';
end
```

I believe the key part in this code is

```
b(c).XData + b(c).XOffset
```

since I have read online that Matlab on its own cant position them, so we need to calculate their positions.

so my guess is that **b(c).XOffset** is supposed to return some values, but I in my case it only returns

> ans =
>
> ```
>  0
> ```

I have also tried the solution proposed [here](http://%20http://jianchen.info/how-to-place-errorbars-on-grouped-bar-graph-in-matlab/) but it also didnt work.

I use Matlab R2018b.

Comment: I could not reproduce the exact behavior you have here with the answer to the last question, but I did find an issue with that answer.  Please try the [new answer I added](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59359488/1789543) and see if that solves your problem here.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar question recently and I've found the following code works for me (unfortunately I don't remember the original post I adapted this from though):

```
ngroups = size(means, 1);
nbars = size(means, 2);
% Calculating the width for each bar group
groupwidth = min(0.8, nbars/(nbars + 1.5));
for i = 1:nbars
    x = (1:ngroups) - groupwidth/2 + (2*i-1) * groupwidth / (2*nbars);
    errorbar(x, means(:,i), ci95(:,i), 'LineStyle', 'none');
end
```

I realise this doesn't answer the question of why b(c).XOffset was returning 0 for you, but might provide an alternative method.